# Update array Values Reactively

Tags: angular, meteor, angular-meteor

I have a angular2-meteor project, i have a colecction of this object:

```
{ name:"name1", value:4 }
```

and i want an array of value property like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and i want the changes maked in the collection appears reactively on my array. For example: if i insert a new document on my collection i want a new item in my array of values.
In my client side i subscribe to this collection like this:

```
this.collectSub = MeteorObservable.subscribe('collection', options).subscribe(() => {
    this.objects = MyCollection.find({}, {
      sort: {
        name: nameOrder
      }
    }).zone();
  });
```

I try to use map function over this.object, but this dont work.

Any help is welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you try this:

```
this.collectSub = MeteorObservable.subscribe('collection', options).subscribe(() => {
    this.array = MyCollection.find({}, {
      sort: {
        name: nameOrder
      }
    }).map((item) => item.value).zone();
  });
```

??

if you don't want to use map on the cursor you can use map like this:

```
let collectionMock = [{name:"name1", value:1},{name:"name2", value:2},{name:"name3", value:3},{name:"name1", value:4}];
let result = collectionMock.map((item) => item.value);
```

I don't really know the angular way, but i think if "this.objects" is an ReactiveVar you can wrap your map execution with Tracker.autorun like:

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
    this.resultArray = this.objects.map((item) => item.value);    
    });
```